# Can combustion create ATP

Tags: biology, creature-design, aliens, biochemistry, metabolism

Could the heat and light from slow and controlled combustion produce ATP from ADP and inorganic phosphate? Could the heat and light drive proton pumps and then could ATP synthase produce ATP from the resulting proton gradient? How would atp be moved to the fuel and then release its phosphate bond to generate the energy for it to combust? How is ADP and inorganic phosphate moved to ATP synthase?

Comment: That's basically exactly what aerobic respiration *is*...

Comment: Yes - proton pumps driven by light can produce enough emf to drive ATP synthesis. Here's an example of a synthetic system: https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/9548252/

Comment: You will need to be a bit  more precise in your wording : The light from a controlled combustion can create ATP (any plant sitting at a reasonable distance from a bright fire does that) - but your question seems to look for a more ... direct (?) way? Logan R Kearsley is right in pointing out that aerobic respiration (what is going on in any one of your cells at any given time) IS combustion, in a way. You are looking for a flame, though, right (because you are asking about light?)? So a plant sitting next to a fire is too meta, and respiration is too non-flammable - what are you looking for?

Answer (score 2):

While combustion can create the conditions for switching the direction of certain reactions (e.g. making iron from iron oxide), making ATP from ADP in a burning fire is unlikely.

It would require the ADP to be unaffected from all the radicals bumping around during the combustion, when organic molecules are more than happy to join the dances when radicals are around

Comment: Well, so would the heat and energy be enough to drive a proton pump? ATP when broken down, also produces heat and energy.